# xml parsing using cURL to connect gives me this:Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I am using XAMPP with enabled cURL, and i try to parse xml produced by php and i get this error, any help please?
my search.php code:

```
   <?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("places");
$location = $_GET['location'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
if($location!="" && $type != "" ){
    $result=mysql_query("select * from accommodation WHERE location='$location' AND type= '$type'");
    }

elseif($location != "")
    {$result=mysql_query("select * from accommodation WHERE location='$location'");
}

else{echo "ERROR";
}

echo"<places>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<place>";
        echo "<placeid>$row[ID]</placeid>";
        echo "<name>$row[name]</name>";
        echo "<type>$row[type]</type>";
        echo "<location>$row[location]</location>";
        echo "<availableroom>$row[availability]</availableroom>";
        echo "</place>";
    }


echo"</places>";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

and here is my cURL code:
I get location and type from form in another page using POST.
Also I used---> echo "The server sent back : ". htmlentities($response); but I don't get any thing in response only same error message

```
 <?php
    $l = $_POST['location'];
    $t = $_POST['type'];
    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL,"search.php?location=$l&type=$t");
    curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($connection,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($connection);
    echo "The server sent back : ". htmlentities($response);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    for($index=0; $index < count($xml->hotel); $index++)
    {
        echo $xml->hotel[$index]->hotelid . "<br />";
        echo $xml->hotel[$index]->name . "<br />";
        echo $xml->hotel[$index]->type . "<br />";
        echo $xml->hotel[$index]->location . "<br />";
        echo $xml->hotel[$index]->availableroom . "<br />";
    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether you're using curl to fetch the XML from an external or local host (doing that locally doesn't make much sense) but either way `"search.php?location=$l&type=$t"` is not a valid URL curl can fetch, which is why `$result` is empty, which is why `$xml` is false instead of an object, which is why you get the error you get.

Add protocol and hostname to your URL. Make sure `$xml != false` after `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response)`.

Comment: This is an assignment I am doing so I work at home and using xampp, so all files are local in .htdocs in xampp. Could you tell me what is wrong with URL? search.php is the code I have included at top (first code) which provide xml out put.

Comment: Try passing the URL as `http://localhost/search.php?location=$l&type=$t` . cURL is meant to communicate to a server using an external protocol (which is why I wrote it makes no sense to use it to get data from localhost, although it's possible) so it needs full URL with the protocol://host part.